# What should I do before root?

Tags: root-access, htc-desire, htc

I am going to root HTC Desire (with Android 2.2).
How can I do best backup, and how can I get sure that I won't lost my whatsapp history and other files?

Comment: Rooting the HTC Desire will typically not cause data loss (incl. WA history). Your photographs and stuff typically reside on the sdcard, so there's nothing you need to do either. Depending on your other apps, you might check their respective backup strategies PS, here's WhatsApps's: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/23753886

Answer (score 0):

Download Titanium Backup, it can backup and restore all your apps, whatsapp included. If you want you can also install a custom recovery like twrp to backup the entire device memory and firmware

Comment: But Titanium Backup needs root?

Comment: Yes, of course. I recommend the paid version, worth every cent.

Comment: But my questin was: What should I do BEFORE root?

Comment: Nothing, you don't need to prepare anything.